# linking with `x86_64-linux-musl-gcc` failed: exit status: 1

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, rust-cargo

I am trying to cross compile the rust app in macOS Monterey 12.3.1 with M1 chip so that I could run the rust app in alpine linux in docker container. When I am using this command to compile the app:

```
CROSS_COMPILE=x86_64-linux-musl- RUSTFLAGS="-C target-feature=-crt-static" cargo build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

shows error:

```
error: linking with `x86_64-linux-musl-gcc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: "x86_64-linux-musl-gcc" "-m64" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/fortune-66ee421a3d6e3b3c.fortune.63b2375e-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/fortune-66ee421a3d6e3b3c.fortune.63b2375e-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/fortune-66ee421a3d6e3b3c.fortune.63b2375e-cgu.10.rcgu.o" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/fortune-66ee421a3d6e3b3c.fortune.63b2375e-cgu.11.rcgu.o" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/fortune-66ee421a3d6e3b3c.fortune.63b2375e-cgu.12.rcgu.o" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/fortune-66ee421a3d6e3b3c.fortune.63b2375e-cgu.13.rcgu.o" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/fortune-66ee421a3d6e3b3c.fortune.63b2375e-cgu.14.rcgu.o" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/fortune-66ee421a3d6e3b3c.fortune.63b2375e-cgu.15.rcgu.o" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/fortune-66ee421a3d6e3b3c.fortune.63b2375e-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/fortune-66ee421a3d6e3b3c.fortune.63b2375e-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/fortune-66ee421a3d6e3b3c.fortune.63b2375e-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/fortune-66ee421a3d6e3b3c.fortune.63b2375e-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/fortune-66ee421a3d6e3b3c.fortune.63b2375e-cgu.6.rcgu.o" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/fortune-66ee421a3d6e3b3c.fortune.63b2375e-cgu.7.rcgu.o" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/fortune-66ee421a3d6e3b3c.fortune.63b2375e-cgu.8.rcgu.o" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/fortune-66ee421a3d6e3b3c.fortune.63b2375e-cgu.9.rcgu.o" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/fortune-66ee421a3d6e3b3c.als9akela8bt3uk.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps" "-L" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/release/deps" "-L" "/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib" "-L" "/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib" "-L" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-a5403edcb6d58bf6/out" "-L" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/librust_wheel-00902c352b3f2452.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libconfig-cdf1121056f01fa9.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libini-baccd911e21f2baa.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libserde_hjson-a3ca5b393bc18c12.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libserde-a149be284464586e.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libnum_traits-8cd7e27971195be4.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libyaml_rust-870c039f63a1ef10.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/liblinked_hash_map-f193d192da399cc3.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libnom-e894b0573ee83340.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/liblexical_core-adb69b5349c5c039.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libstatic_assertions-04860f757594c1c3.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libarrayvec-27476d4e5591a510.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libreqwest-fe50b8c292cbf8a6.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libhyper_tls-1310c474f28288da.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libserde_urlencoded-d29f8ef7319ae572.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libipnet-26095768283b3d24.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtokio_native_tls-6f1612fc5430c496.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libnative_tls-68344b11299211ad.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libopenssl_probe-694309879794c201.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libopenssl-4907fb7e39035744.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libforeign_types-d0e56b9eca01ff6f.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libforeign_types_shared-df752d3167dea5b5.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libopenssl_sys-318a4e3e66f1a6ee.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/liburl-86cd9fa83e1a1581.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libidna-3c67f46cd2fd9473.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libunicode_normalization-66c1b9dd2294b8cb.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtinyvec-b3ee1a4bcd5c100f.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libtinyvec_macros-bef6fe7e5df78f4b.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/liblibc-c097b71320db773c.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/liballoc-37d12500bef99331.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-63d6ff8598946320.rlib" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libcore-972b93109ce1fa5e.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libcompiler_builtins-71972cde1db06d51.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lssl" "-lcrypto" "-lpq" "-lgcc_s" "-lc" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-znoexecstack" "-L" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib" "-o" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/fortune-66ee421a3d6e3b3c" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-zrelro,-znow" "-Wl,-O1" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdiesel-5117ba9d7008b221.rlib(diesel-5117ba9d7008b221.diesel.1e507974-cgu.12.rcgu.o): in function `<diesel::pg::connection::row::PgRow as diesel::row::Row<diesel::pg::backend::Pg>>::take':
          diesel.1e507974-cgu.12:(.text._ZN102_$LT$diesel..pg..connection..row..PgRow$u20$as$u20$diesel..row..Row$LT$diesel..pg..backend..Pg$GT$$GT$4take17hfcd5b9afa869e644E+0x27): undefined reference to `PQgetisnull'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: diesel.1e507974-cgu.12:(.text._ZN102_$LT$diesel..pg..connection..row..PgRow$u20$as$u20$diesel..row..Row$LT$diesel..pg..backend..Pg$GT$$GT$4take17hfcd5b9afa869e644E+0x3e): undefined reference to `PQgetvalue'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: diesel.1e507974-cgu.12:(.text._ZN102_$LT$diesel..pg..connection..row..PgRow$u20$as$u20$diesel..row..Row$LT$diesel..pg..backend..Pg$GT$$GT$4take17hfcd5b9afa869e644E+0x4f): undefined reference to `PQgetlength'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdiesel-5117ba9d7008b221.rlib(diesel-5117ba9d7008b221.diesel.1e507974-cgu.13.rcgu.o): in function `<diesel::pg::connection::PgConnection as diesel::connection::Connection>::establish':
          diesel.1e507974-cgu.13:(.text._ZN87_$LT$diesel..pg..connection..PgConnection$u20$as$u20$diesel..connection..Connection$GT$9establish17h8aa49ec29366fe8bE+0x19f): undefined reference to `PQfinish'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: diesel.1e507974-cgu.13:(.text._ZN87_$LT$diesel..pg..connection..PgConnection$u20$as$u20$diesel..connection..Connection$GT$9establish17h8aa49ec29366fe8bE+0x26b): undefined reference to `PQsetNoticeProcessor'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: diesel.1e507974-cgu.13:(.text._ZN87_$LT$diesel..pg..connection..PgConnection$u20$as$u20$diesel..connection..Connection$GT$9establish17h8aa49ec29366fe8bE+0x32b): undefined reference to `PQfinish'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: diesel.1e507974-cgu.13:(.text._ZN87_$LT$diesel..pg..connection..PgConnection$u20$as$u20$diesel..connection..Connection$GT$9establish17h8aa49ec29366fe8bE+0x346): undefined reference to `PQfinish'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdiesel-5117ba9d7008b221.rlib(diesel-5117ba9d7008b221.diesel.1e507974-cgu.13.rcgu.o): in function `<diesel::pg::connection::PgConnection as diesel::connection::Connection>::execute':
          diesel.1e507974-cgu.13:(.text._ZN87_$LT$diesel..pg..connection..PgConnection$u20$as$u20$diesel..connection..Connection$GT$7execute17hf7b1748aed6baae0E+0x1b4): undefined reference to `PQcmdTuples'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: diesel.1e507974-cgu.13:(.text._ZN87_$LT$diesel..pg..connection..PgConnection$u20$as$u20$diesel..connection..Connection$GT$7execute17hf7b1748aed6baae0E+0x1e5): undefined reference to `PQclear'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: diesel.1e507974-cgu.13:(.text._ZN87_$LT$diesel..pg..connection..PgConnection$u20$as$u20$diesel..connection..Connection$GT$7execute17hf7b1748aed6baae0E+0x29a): undefined reference to `PQclear'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdiesel-5117ba9d7008b221.rlib(diesel-5117ba9d7008b221.diesel.1e507974-cgu.3.rcgu.o): in function `core::ptr::drop_in_place<diesel::pg::connection::result::PgErrorInformation>':
          diesel.1e507974-cgu.3:(.text._ZN4core3ptr71drop_in_place$LT$diesel..pg..connection..result..PgErrorInformation$GT$17hc4253a47f03c3f62E+0x5): undefined reference to `PQclear'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdiesel-5117ba9d7008b221.rlib(diesel-5117ba9d7008b221.diesel.1e507974-cgu.3.rcgu.o): in function `diesel::pg::connection::result::PgResult::new':
          diesel.1e507974-cgu.3:(.text._ZN6diesel2pg10connection6result8PgResult3new17h94544362d159079fE+0x15): undefined reference to `PQresultStatus'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: diesel.1e507974-cgu.3:(.text._ZN6diesel2pg10connection6result8PgResult3new17h94544362d159079fE+0xb3): undefined reference to `PQclear'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: diesel.1e507974-cgu.3:(.text._ZN6diesel2pg10connection6result8PgResult3new17h94544362d159079fE+0xc6): undefined reference to `PQresultErrorField'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: diesel.1e507974-cgu.3:(.text._ZN6diesel2pg10connection6result8PgResult3new17h94544362d159079fE+0x1c1): undefined reference to `PQclear'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdiesel-5117ba9d7008b221.rlib(diesel-5117ba9d7008b221.diesel.1e507974-cgu.3.rcgu.o): in function `diesel::pg::connection::result::PgResult::num_rows':
          diesel.1e507974-cgu.3:(.text._ZN6diesel2pg10connection6result8PgResult8num_rows17h699fffa9bd2b0118E+0x6): undefined reference to `PQntuples'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdiesel-5117ba9d7008b221.rlib(diesel-5117ba9d7008b221.diesel.1e507974-cgu.3.rcgu.o): in function `<diesel::pg::connection::result::PgErrorInformation as diesel::result::DatabaseErrorInformation>::message':
          diesel.1e507974-cgu.3:(.text._ZN111_$LT$diesel..pg..connection..result..PgErrorInformation$u20$as$u20$diesel..result..DatabaseErrorInformation$GT$7message17he8420a61e14dc590E+0x14): undefined reference to `PQresultErrorField'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: diesel.1e507974-cgu.3:(.text._ZN111_$LT$diesel..pg..connection..result..PgErrorInformation$u20$as$u20$diesel..result..DatabaseErrorInformation$GT$7message17he8420a61e14dc590E+0x5b): undefined reference to `PQresultErrorMessage'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdiesel-5117ba9d7008b221.rlib(diesel-5117ba9d7008b221.diesel.1e507974-cgu.3.rcgu.o): in function `<diesel::pg::connection::result::PgErrorInformation as diesel::result::DatabaseErrorInformation>::details':
          diesel.1e507974-cgu.3:(.text._ZN111_$LT$diesel..pg..connection..result..PgErrorInformation$u20$as$u20$diesel..result..DatabaseErrorInformation$GT$7details17h41d8af601be65cb3E+0xf): undefined reference to `PQresultErrorField'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdiesel-5117ba9d7008b221.rlib(diesel-5117ba9d7008b221.diesel.1e507974-cgu.3.rcgu.o): in function `<diesel::pg::connection::result::PgErrorInformation as diesel::result::DatabaseErrorInformation>::hint':
          diesel.1e507974-cgu.3:(.text._ZN111_$LT$diesel..pg..connection..result..PgErrorInformation$u20$as$u20$diesel..result..DatabaseErrorInformation$GT$4hint17h046c6399f43601e1E+0xf): undefined reference to `PQresultErrorField'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdiesel-5117ba9d7008b221.rlib(diesel-5117ba9d7008b221.diesel.1e507974-cgu.3.rcgu.o): in function `<diesel::pg::connection::result::PgErrorInformation as diesel::result::DatabaseErrorInformation>::table_name':
          diesel.1e507974-cgu.3:(.text._ZN111_$LT$diesel..pg..connection..result..PgErrorInformation$u20$as$u20$diesel..result..DatabaseErrorInformation$GT$10table_name17h07244da9a1cd207bE+0xf): undefined reference to `PQresultErrorField'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdiesel-5117ba9d7008b221.rlib(diesel-5117ba9d7008b221.diesel.1e507974-cgu.3.rcgu.o): in function `<diesel::pg::connection::result::PgErrorInformation as diesel::result::DatabaseErrorInformation>::column_name':
          diesel.1e507974-cgu.3:(.text._ZN111_$LT$diesel..pg..connection..result..PgErrorInformation$u20$as$u20$diesel..result..DatabaseErrorInformation$GT$11column_name17h64121ff201f888e9E+0xf): undefined reference to `PQresultErrorField'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdiesel-5117ba9d7008b221.rlib(diesel-5117ba9d7008b221.diesel.1e507974-cgu.3.rcgu.o): in function `<diesel::pg::connection::result::PgErrorInformation as diesel::result::DatabaseErrorInformation>::constraint_name':
          diesel.1e507974-cgu.3:(.text._ZN111_$LT$diesel..pg..connection..result..PgErrorInformation$u20$as$u20$diesel..result..DatabaseErrorInformation$GT$15constraint_name17h06c3e8fcc2f38e98E+0xf): undefined reference to `PQresultErrorField'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdiesel-5117ba9d7008b221.rlib(diesel-5117ba9d7008b221.diesel.1e507974-cgu.6.rcgu.o): in function `diesel::pg::connection::stmt::Statement::execute':
          diesel.1e507974-cgu.6:(.text._ZN6diesel2pg10connection4stmt9Statement7execute17h1df5513c7c4c4f77E+0x22f): undefined reference to `PQexecPrepared'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdiesel-5117ba9d7008b221.rlib(diesel-5117ba9d7008b221.diesel.1e507974-cgu.6.rcgu.o): in function `diesel::pg::connection::stmt::Statement::prepare':
          diesel.1e507974-cgu.6:(.text._ZN6diesel2pg10connection4stmt9Statement7prepare17h842bf72e23d6d98bE+0x208): undefined reference to `PQprepare'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: diesel.1e507974-cgu.6:(.text._ZN6diesel2pg10connection4stmt9Statement7prepare17h842bf72e23d6d98bE+0x313): undefined reference to `PQclear'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdiesel-5117ba9d7008b221.rlib(diesel-5117ba9d7008b221.diesel.1e507974-cgu.9.rcgu.o): in function `diesel::pg::connection::raw::RawConnection::establish':
          diesel.1e507974-cgu.9:(.text._ZN6diesel2pg10connection3raw13RawConnection9establish17h4731f22e8f334bd1E+0x5f): undefined reference to `PQconnectdb'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: diesel.1e507974-cgu.9:(.text._ZN6diesel2pg10connection3raw13RawConnection9establish17h4731f22e8f334bd1E+0x6b): undefined reference to `PQstatus'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: diesel.1e507974-cgu.9:(.text._ZN6diesel2pg10connection3raw13RawConnection9establish17h4731f22e8f334bd1E+0x88): undefined reference to `PQfinish'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdiesel-5117ba9d7008b221.rlib(diesel-5117ba9d7008b221.diesel.1e507974-cgu.9.rcgu.o): in function `<diesel::pg::connection::raw::RawConnection as core::ops::drop::Drop>::drop':
          diesel.1e507974-cgu.9:(.text._ZN84_$LT$diesel..pg..connection..raw..RawConnection$u20$as$u20$core..ops..drop..Drop$GT$4drop17h6af0303d0f1b6abfE+0x5): undefined reference to `PQfinish'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdiesel-5117ba9d7008b221.rlib(diesel-5117ba9d7008b221.diesel.1e507974-cgu.9.rcgu.o): in function `_ZN6diesel2pg10connection3raw18last_error_message17h47198c771432cdf0E.llvm.5575034157405227121':
          diesel.1e507974-cgu.9:(.text._ZN6diesel2pg10connection3raw18last_error_message17h47198c771432cdf0E.llvm.5575034157405227121+0x16): undefined reference to `PQerrorMessage'
          /opt/homebrew/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.9_1/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/fortune/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/deps/libdiesel-5117ba9d7008b221.rlib(diesel-5117ba9d7008b221.diesel.1e507974-cgu.9.rcgu.o): in function `<diesel::pg::connection::raw::RawResult as core::ops::drop::Drop>::drop':
          diesel.1e507974-cgu.9:(.text._ZN80_$LT$diesel..pg..connection..raw..RawResult$u20$as$u20$core..ops..drop..Drop$GT$4drop17hfdec9cc1e7a2917eE+0x5): undefined reference to `PQclear'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

  = help: some `extern` functions couldn't be found; some native libraries may need to be installed or have their path specified
  = note: use the `-l` flag to specify native libraries to link
  = note: use the `cargo:rustc-link-lib` directive to specify the native libraries to link with Cargo (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#cargorustc-link-libkindname)

warning: `fortune` (bin "fortune") generated 4 warnings
error: could not compile `fortune` due to previous error; 4 warnings emitted
```

why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As for cross compile, probably you could give [`cargo-zigbuild`](https://github.com/messense/cargo-zigbuild) a try.